# This code works in php 5.6 (server status), why doesn't it work in php 7.4?

Tags: php

Good afternoon, I'm new to php, so I kinda need some help here. This code was working in php 5.6, the server status was readable and was online, but when I use php 7.4 the server status becomes offline but actually the server was online. Can anyone help me? Does the code need to be changed for php 7.4? Can anyone help me to change it, please?

```
<?php

       $file = file ("http://xxx/ServerDisplay.ini");
         foreach($file as $line)
         {
                 if(strspn($line, "[") != 1)
               parse_str($line);
         }

       function statuscheck ($ serverip, $ port) { 
               $ Sockres = @ fsockopen ($ serverip, $ port, $ errno, $ errstr, 1); 
               if (! $ sockres) { 
               return "&nbsp;<font color='red'><b>Off-Line</b></font>"; 
               } else { 
                    @fclose($sockres); 
                    return "&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color='green'><b>On-Line</b></font>"; 
                    } 
               } 

          //Вывод на экран статус сервера и онлайн рас 

          $serverip = "xxxxxxx"; 

          echo "<b><font size=2 color=#ffffff>"; 
          echo "<div> "; 
          echo "Login: " . statuscheck($serverip, "10001"); 
          echo "</div> "; 
          echo "<div> "; 
          echo "Zone:" . statuscheck($serverip, "27780"); 
          echo "</div> "; 

           $serverip = "xxxxxxxx";                             
           echo "Total Online : $UserNum";  

?>
```

*I have censored my server IP

Comment: Avoid keeping space between $ and keyword ($ serverip, $ port). Remove the space and try again.

Comment: Turn on error_reporting, remove [error suppression](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) from your code and check the error(s) you get

Comment: @Karthick actually there is no space $serverip the space was happen during my copy paste here, my issue is that code was work in php 5.6 (the server status was online) i dont know why it didnt work in php 7.4 (status become offline)

Comment: @kerbholz my issue is that code was work in php 5.6 (the server status was online) i dont know why it didnt work in php 7.4 (status become offline)

Comment: @wack I tried your same script over PHP 7.4.0/Apache 2.4.1 with the IP of localhost - 127.0.0.1 for ports 80/443 which worked perfectly and showed On-Line status. First of all, put a telnet to the mentioned server from source PC/server and make sure ports are listening & open to the destination.

telnet $serverip 10001

Comment: No need to repeat your problem, we can read it in your question. Probably a deprecated function (available in 5, but not in 7) somewhere or a missing PHP module. Have you done any debugging (error_reporting etc.)?

Comment: As already suggested, remove the `@` which is hiding any errors that line might throw.

Answer (score 0):

Status shows On-Line with the same script.

```
$file = file ("http://karthick.stackoverflow.com/php.ini");
         foreach($file as $line)
         {
                 if(strspn($line, "[") != 1)
               parse_str($line);
         }

       function statuscheck ($serverip, $port) { 
               $sockres = @fsockopen ($serverip, $port, $errno, $errstr, 1); 
               if (!$sockres) { 
                return "&nbsp;<font color='red'><b>Off-Line</b></font>"; 
               } else { 
                    @fclose($sockres); 
                    return "&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color='green'><b>On-Line</b></font>"; 
                    } 
               } 

          $serverip = "127.0.0.1"; 

          echo "<b><font size=2 color=#ffffff>"; 
          echo "<div> "; 
          echo "Login: " . statuscheck($serverip, "80"); 
          echo "</div> "; 
          echo "<div> "; 
          echo "Zone:" . statuscheck($serverip, "443"); 
          echo "</div> "; 

           $serverip = "127.0.0.1";                             
           //echo "Total Online : $UserNum";
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: so there is no problem with my script ?, but i try to use the same script it didnt work in my web which use php 7.4, but when i use it at my localhost / my web using php 5.6 its work fine no issue with that. do you have another solution ?

Comment: @wack Couldn't see any problem with your script and it worked fine. First of all, you need to make sure those destination server ports are listening from your source web server(not localhost). Your destination server could be online but ports should be opened from your source web server to destination server before execute this script. If it's working from localhost means, those ports would have opened from your PC to that destination server.